# Insert entire JSON to database after decode using PHP PDO

Tags: php, json, pdo, foreach, insert

I want insert this json from jquery.ajax (content of index VALOR don't always have data):

```
[
{
    "input": "calleFiscal",
    "valor": ""
},
{
    "input": "numFiscal",
    "valor": "numero fiscal"
},
{
    "input": "colFiscal",
    "valor": ""
},
{
    "input": "delefacionFiscal",
    "valor": ""
},
{
    "input": "estadoFiscal",
    "valor": "11"
},
{
    "input": "calleComercial",
    "valor": "calle comercial"
},
{
    "input": "numComercial",
    "valor": ""
},
{
    "input": "colComercial",
    "valor": ""
},
{
    "input": "delefacionComercial",
    "valor": ""
},
{
    "input": "estadoComercial",
    "valor": "3"
},
{
    "input": "calleEntrega",
    "valor": ""
},
{
    "input": "numEntrega",
    "valor": ""
},
{
    "input": "colEntrega",
    "valor": "colonia entrega"
},
{
    "input": "delefacionEntrega",
    "valor": ""
},
{
    "input": "estadoEntrega",
    "valor": "11"
}
]
```

Is created by mapping a div using jquery, and I try to insert in a database with this:

```
$addresses = json_decode($this->dataActionClient['addresses'],true);

$sqlAd = "INSERT INTO t_direcciones_clientes (Id_Cliente,Calle,Numero,Colonia,Municipio,Estado,Tipo) VALUES (:idc,:calle,:num,:col,:deleg,:edo,:tipo)";
$resultAd = $this->dbConnect->prepare($sqlAd) or die ($sqlAd);

$fields = array('calle','num','col','deleg','edo');
$types = array('fiscal','comercial','entrega');

$resultAd->bindParam(':idc',$id_cliente,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$counType = 0;

foreach ($addresses as $key => $value) {
    $key++;
    $resultAd->bindParam(':'.$fields[$key], $value['valor']);
    if ($key == 4 || $key == 9) {
        $resultAd->bindParam(':tipo', $types[$counType]);
        $counType++;
        $resultAd->execute();
    }
}
```

Explanation of that code:

I have 3 areas **(fiscal, comercial, entrega)** and each one has 5 inputs **(Calle, Numero, Colonia, Municipio, Estado, Tipo)** then I need insert 3 rows in a table and these 3 rows have the same **Id_Cliente** but have differente **Tipo** and different content of your 5 inputs.
But doesn't work, and display this error:

```
Tried to bind parameter number 0. SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters.
```

Maybe my method is wrong and if exists any way to do this, I was the grateful.

**Edited**

I solve my problem changing some values according system functionanily but thanks to everyone.

Comment: Sure.. wait a bit, I forgot put two lines more

Comment: You are using question mark placeholders - `?`, but creating/using named placeholders `':'.$fields[$key]`?? Also, `bindParam()` use a 1-index, where your array is a 0-index (which is what I believe your error is stating `Tried to bind parameter number 0`), so you might need to increase your keys by 1.

Comment: Hmm my first comment was wrong, you're not binding 2 parameters, but 5, the statement is getting executed when $key hits 4, so you are 2 short... and what @Sean said ;)

Comment: You are stilling using question mark placeholders - `?` - in your `prepare()`, but creating/using named placeholders  - `':'.$fields[$key]` - in your `bindParam()`. for example - `?` != `:idc`,  `?` != `:calle`, etc.

Comment: Sure, I fixed that.. but now appear this error: COUNT field incorrect or syntax error.

Comment: JSON is just a string that can be interpreted. Why not just store the string in the database?

Comment: You're right.. Also do that to get and save more fast my data, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add 1 more counter, that you can reset to 0 after 5 loops. Try this -

```
$counField = 0; // counter to access field array, will be reset to 0 after 5 loops
$counType = 0;

foreach ($addresses as $key => $value) {
    $resultAd->bindParam(':'.$fields[$counField], $value['valor']);
    if ($key == 4 || $key == 9 || $key == 14) {
        $resultAd->bindParam(':tipo', $types[$counType]);
        $counType++;
        $counField++; // increase if the last of 5 loops
        $resultAd->execute();
    }
    else {
        $counField++; // increase if not the last of 5 loops 
    }
}
```

here is a phpFiddle example that shows the outcome - http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/k4b-nja

Comment: Thanks, but I solve my answer of different way and I post my correct answer in the edited post. But thanks for your time.